# this variable in elements

Tags: html, reactjs

I'm wondering if there's anyway to have a "this" variable in a element in react, or in normal HTML like this:

```html
<button onClick="()=>this.className=this.previousSibling.value">bye bye bye</button>
```

Comment: In react you should _never_ be set `element.innerHTML`. Instead you should let react re-render based on updated state.

Comment: It was just as an example, I'll update my code to what I actually want, Let me know if there's a better way to do that btw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### HTML

Leaving React aside, `this` is set to the element in an `onclick` handler. Though you have to bind the function via the `function` keyword and not an arrow `() =>` function. Arrow functions capture the value of `this` from where there are declared.

```js
const button = document.getElementById('button')
button.onclick = function() { this.innerHTML = 'Hello' }
```

```html
<button id="button">bye bye bye</button>
```

---

### React

In react, however, this is a really bad practice. You want to let React render everything for you from your state, and you do not want to have to manage a bunch of fiddly side effects with element references.

So when you click a button:

1. Set state in your component according to what clicking that button means.
2. Use that state when you render your component to change how things render.

In general, if you want to run this code in react:

```
this.className=this.previousSibling.value
```

Then you have the entirely wrong approach.

Instead that previous sibling should have a value stored in state, and you click your button, you have a function that knows about that state and does the right thing with it.

Avoid, if at all possible, directly referencing DOM elements in React. You will save a lot of headaches when your applications gets larger and more complex.